# how I can get validation message while passing invalid value in ASP.NET 5 routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this routing

```
[HttpGet("{check_id:long:min(1)}")]
```

while passing 0 value in check_id, it gives `404` response code, that's perfectly working.

But I also want a message in response. How can I implement it?

Comment: you can use Route constraints, check this [Link](https://samanthaneilen.github.io/2018/10/09/using-route-constraints.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the reason of *why* a route match fails is not exposed outside the ASP.NET Core routing middleware, only logged, so I think it's not possible to react with custom code to the route matching failure with the specific reason you are interested in (route parameter constraint in this case).

A solution, although a little bit hacky, could be to implement your own custom middleware like so (you have to adapt controller and parameter names):

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    // ... code skipped
    app.UseRouting();
    // put this after the .UseRouting() or .UseAuthorization() call
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/WeatherForecast")) // controller name
        {
            var end = context.GetEndpoint();
            if (end == null) // if the endpoint is null it means that the route matching failed (wrong path OR route parameter constraint failure)
            {
                // you could put more logic here to get the route parameter and check if it's valid or not
                context.Response.StatusCode = 404;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("You supplied a wrong parameter");
                return; // short circuit pipeline
            }
        }
        await next.Invoke();
    });
    // ... code skipped
}
```

For more info, you can refer to the code of the Middleware and Matcher classes responsible of route selection:

[EndpointRoutingMiddleware.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Routing/src/EndpointRoutingMiddleware.cs)

[DfaMatcher.cs](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Http/Routing/src/Matching/DfaMatcher.cs)